# Antlr - Why it expect FunctionCall but PrintCommand gave

Tags: java, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

my Antlr-grammar expect a FunctionCall but in my example-code for the compiler built by antlr, i wrote a print-command. Does someone know why and how to fix that? The print-command is named: `RetroBox.show();` The print-command should be recognised from **blockstatements** to **blockstatement** to **statement** to **localFunctionCall** to **printCommand**

Here my Antrl-grammar:

```
grammar Mars;
// ******************************LEXER 
BEGIN*****************************************

// Keywords
FUNC:                           'func';
ENTRY:                          'entry';
VARI:                           'vari';
VARF:                           'varf';
VARC:                           'varc';
VARS:                           'vars';
LET:                            'let';
INCREMENTS:                     'increments';
RETROBOX:                       'retrobox';
SHOW:                           'show';

// Literals

DECIMAL_LITERAL:    ('0' | [1-9] (Digits? | '_'+ Digits)) [lL]?;

FLOAT_LITERAL:      (Digits '.' Digits? | '.' Digits) ExponentPart? [fFdD]?
         |       Digits (ExponentPart [fFdD]? | [fFdD])
         ;

CHAR_LITERAL:       '\'' (~['\\\r\n] | EscapeSequence) '\'';

STRING_LITERAL:     '"' (~["\\\r\n] | EscapeSequence)* '"';

// Seperators

ORBRACKET:                          '(';
CRBRACKET:                          ')';
OEBRACKET:                          '{';
CEBRACKET:                          '}';
SEMI:                               ';';
POINT:                              '.';

// Operators

ASSIGN:             '=';

// Whitespace and comments

WS:                 [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
COMMENT:            '/*' .*? '*/'    -> channel(HIDDEN);
LINE_COMMENT:       '//' ~[\r\n]*    -> channel(HIDDEN);

// Identifiers

IDENTIFIER:         Letter LetterOrDigit*;

// Fragment rules

fragment ExponentPart
    : [eE] [+-]? Digits
    ;  

fragment EscapeSequence
    : '\\' [btnfr"'\\]
    | '\\' ([0-3]? [0-7])? [0-7]
    | '\\' 'u'+ HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
    ;

fragment HexDigits
    : HexDigit ((HexDigit | '_')* HexDigit)?
    ;

fragment HexDigit
    : [0-9a-fA-F]
    ;

fragment Digits
    : [0-9] ([0-9_]* [0-9])?
    ;

fragment LetterOrDigit
    : Letter
    | [0-9]
    ;

fragment Letter
    : [a-zA-Z$_] // these are the "java letters" below 0x7F
    | ~[\u0000-\u007F\uD800-\uDBFF] // covers all characters above 0x7F                 which are not a surrogate
    | [\uD800-\uDBFF] [\uDC00-\uDFFF] // covers UTF-16 surrogate pairs encodings for U+10000 to U+10FFFF
    ;

// *******************************LEXER     END****************************************

// *****************************PARSER BEGIN*****************************************

program
    : mainfunction  #Programm
    | /*EMPTY*/              #Garnichts
    ;

mainfunction
    : FUNC VARI ENTRY ORBRACKET CRBRACKET block  #NormaleHauptmethode
    ;

block
    : '{' blockStatement '}'   #CodeBlock
    | /*EMPTY*/                #EmptyCodeBlock
    ;

blockStatement
    : statement* #Befehl
    ;

statement
    : localVariableDeclaration
    | localVariableInitialization
    | localFunctionImplementation
    | localFunctionCall
    ;

expression
    : left=expression op='%'
    | left=expression op=('*' | '/') right=expression
    | left=expression op=('+' | '-') right=expression
    | neg='-' right=expression
    | number
    | IDENTIFIER
    | '(' expression ')'
    ;

number
    : DECIMAL_LITERAL
    | FLOAT_LITERAL
    ;

localFunctionImplementation
    : FUNC primitiveType IDENTIFIER ORBRACKET CRBRACKET block #Methodenimplementierung
    ;

localFunctionCall
    : IDENTIFIER ORBRACKET CRBRACKET SEMI #Methodenaufruf
    | printCommand #RetroBoxShowCommand
    ;

printCommand
    : RETROBOX POINT SHOW ORBRACKET params=primitiveLiteral CRBRACKET SEMI     #PrintCommandWP
    ;

localVariableDeclaration
    : varTypeDek=primitiveType IDENTIFIER SEMI #Variablendeklaration
    ;

localVariableInitialization
    : varTypeIni=primitiveType IDENTIFIER ASSIGN varValue=primitiveLiteral     SEMI #VariableninitKonst
    | varTypeIni=primitiveType IDENTIFIER ASSIGN varValue=expression SEMI #VariableninitExpr
    ;

primitiveLiteral
    : DECIMAL_LITERAL
    | FLOAT_LITERAL
    | STRING_LITERAL
    | CHAR_LITERAL
    ;

primitiveType
    : VARI
    | VARC
    | VARF
    | VARS
    ;

// ******************************PARSER END****************************************
```

Here my example-code:

```
func vari entry()
{
    RetroBox.show("Hallo"); //Should be recognised as print-command
}
```

And here a AST printed from Antlr:

[AST from Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afFuG.png)

Comment: What antlr version and command line are you using? Version 4.7.1 gives me the error: "rule localFunctionCall: must label all alternatives or none".

Comment: Oh sorry, fixed the code above now this kind of error shouldn't get thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your RETROBOX keyword is 'retrobox' but your example code has it typed as 'RetroBox'. Antlr parses 'RetroBox' as an identifier so the following '.' is unexpected.

Antlr should emit an error: "line 3:12 mismatched input '.' expecting '('".

Then it attempts to recover and continue parsing. It tries single token deletion (just ignoring the '.') and finds that that works... except the rule it now matches is #Methodenaufruf instead of #RetroBoxShowCommand.

Comment: So the verification of the keyword 'retrobox' is in antlr case-sensitive, isn't it?

Comment: Yes the lexing is case-sensitive. There's no built-in way to specify case-insensitive tokenising but [this page](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/case-insensitive-lexing.md) offers a couple of approaches if you need it.